# vue.js named views load on app initiation

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue.js and cannot figure out how to load and render a route when initiating a vue app. For example (see below link) how can I render the components of the "path: '/'" when the app loads. Currently they only load when I click on the link.

[jsfiddle complete example here](https://jsfiddle.net/posva/6du90epg/)

```
const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
  { path: '/',
    // a single route can define multiple named components
    // which will be rendered into <router-view>s with corresponding names.
    components: {
    default: Foo,
    a: Bar,
    b: Baz
    }
  },
  {
     path: '/other',
     components: {
     default: Baz,
     a: Bar,
     b: Foo
     }
  }
  ]
})

new Vue({
router,
el: '#app'
})
```

Comment: It may not be happening in fiddle, but when you will run it in local, you will enter say: `localhost:8080/` in the browser, which will render `path: /` only.

Comment: OK I just figured it out. If I delete line

mode: 'history', from router then the named views load on app initiation.

const router = new VueRouter({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
{ path: '/',